# Is "mettre de l'eau dans son moulin" cognate with "all grist to the mill"?

Tags: anglais, sens, expressions

Someone asked in [ELU chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13466011#13466011) how one would say *"mettre de l'eau dans son moulin"* in English.

Can anyone explain exactly what the French understand by the expression? Is the reference to a water-powered mill, or one that might mince up poor quality meat by-products to make sausage meat, for example?

And (crucially) can anyone offer any evidence to prove or disprove my theory that the English version *is in fact related to the French one?*

Please note that my French isn't that good, so if your English is better than my French (very likely! :) I'd appreciate it if you could post comments/answers in English.

Comment: @Laure: I did say my french isn't that good. I'd have felt a right nit if I'd changed it and it *wasn't* a typo.

Comment: What makes you think that the two expressions are related? The only connection I see is that both involve a mill. Also, please explain the English expression, you can't hope this audience to be familiar with English idioms.

Comment: Or did you mean “bring grist to the mill” rather than “all grist to the meal”? That would be far more likely to be related.

Comment: @Gilles: Sorry - I thought all SO posts were *supposed* to be in English, which implies all posters should understand reasonably common usages (or at least, be able to google a few instances to see how it's used in context). In fact, Anglophones wouldn't normally talk about ***bringing** grist to the mill*. Mostly, we say *it's all grist to the mill*, meaning "that (possibly, *unpromising*) material can all be put to good use". Often in contexts where "good use" is in fact "bad use", from the speaker's point of view. No-one says "grist to the **meal**"

Answer (score 3):

I believe the correct usage is "Apporter de l'eau au moulin".

According to [this site](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/149/apporter-de-l-eau-au-moulin-de-quelqu-un/) and [this site](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/apporter%20de%20l%27eau%20au%20moulin%20%28de%20quelqu%27un%29) in french and to [this site](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/grist-to-the-mill.html) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grist), the meaning is not exactly the same.

In french it means that you help someone without knowing it, you're giving him/her "ammunition" against you without you even realize it, while in English it means "everything is a source of profit".

The "point of view" if I can put it that way, is one of a "3rd person" observing an argument between 2 persons for the French idiom, while it's more of a first person (the one who owns the mill) in English.

---

Edit:

It seems that [this site](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/bring%20grist%20to%20the%20mill) links both together.

Apparently, depending on the context these idioms vary in meaning, but they could mean the same thing.

Comment: I appreciate that the "current" meaning may not be considered *exactly* the same. I'm primarily asking if they were originally related (i.e. - have the same basic origin). The English one wouldn't normally be used to mean "everything is a source of profit" - it's more common in contexts like "what you just said actually helps the argument you're disagreeing with", or "this person can creatively make use of things which others see as of little value"

Comment: From what you say and from [here](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/bring%20grist%20to%20the%20mill), apparently, both are linked. This would apparently invalidate this answer, obviously :P

Comment: It's very commendable of you to post that link! I wouldn't ask you to amend your answer if that's not how you see things, but you'll forgive me if I upvote the comment but not the answer!

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the comment. And I'll forgive you :) I'm not sure that the first part of the answer should be removed as it would make the comments irrelevant!

Comment: I assume *you* know exactly how you use the expression in French, and that it's important the person *providing* the grist/water doesn't realise that it will aid someone he probably doesn't want to help at all. I think there's often the same sense in English, but it's also often used in contexts where the speaker *approves* of what the miller can do with "unpromising material". Anyway, +1 following edit.